# Extract attribute Value from JSON String using c#

Tags: c#, json

[image]I'm looking for a best possible way to extract the JSON attribute - RatingData using c#. See the JSON string below.

Please note that the JSON attribute "RatingData" is digitally signed using a private key and I'm trying to verify the digital signature using public key and signature. I need to extract RatingData as it was sent in the JSON to make sure digital signature verification passes. I tried JObject parsing but this technique seems to return spaces and doesn't work well.

Any other technique to retrieve the JSON Attribute information as it is being sent?

```
{
  "DigitalSignature": "MEYCIQDC0RutOfYEIR/3zkUlcIxxxxxx98Ayqq8AIhAP30+Bk8ueY1ABVYJlAQGlhAcWlAMHo3YAqhHIrUykUj",
  "ReceiptPublicKey": "RxxxxxIN7I3IhLjAqrUrx5vZofHYm4DF5srHB0Hzyuf25eW5UVCPOvbr8GvrzqZbq2ZdcQmAaoiyhaBcOdAsjcHYBcfV/tR5uHQRDLWIpNUTawcxB6tX6XGXvd0baPav4LfL2pfqegpx5BhfWdRGmvL6/Yc5bw29IWag/SmabTEZE/C4=",
  "RatingData": {
    "RatingValue": 3,
    "ItemID": "15cc6a0b-9673-4537-b5cc-b205249f44e4",
    "RatingDateTime": "2020-03-21 00:36:49.025",
    "Rating": [
      3,
      3,
      5
    ]
  },
  "RetailersReceiptData": {
    "ConsumerID": "d9e1c467-91c6-4afe-ae7c-86b0a0d0bfb3",
    "RetailerID": "6da5da9f-b42d-4918-ad43-53b2203df54e",
    "RetailerRulePoints": 
    {
      "Enablexxx": 1,
      "Enableyyy": 1,
      "Enablezzz": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "best possible way" mean to you?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aBPBWM). I'm using the Newtonsoft Json library to do the converion

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    static string json = "{ \"DigitalSignature\": \"MEYCIQDC0RutOfYEIR/3zkUlcIxxxxxx98Ayqq8AIhAP30+Bk8ueY1ABVYJlAQGlhAcWlAMHo3YAqhHIrUykUj\",  \"ReceiptPublicKey\": \"RxxxxxIN7I3IhLjAqrUrx5vZofHYm4DF5srHB0Hzyuf25eW5UVCPOvbr8GvrzqZbq2ZdcQmAaoiyhaBcOdAsjcHYBcfV/tR5uHQRDLWIpNUTawcxB6tX6XGXvd0baPav4LfL2pfqegpx5BhfWdRGmvL6/Yc5bw29IWag/SmabTEZE/C4=\",  \"RatingData\": {    \"RatingValue\": 3,    \"ItemID\": \"15cc6a0b-9673-4537-b5cc-b205249f44e4\",    \"RatingDateTime\": \"2020-03-21 00:36:49.025\",    \"Rating\": [      3,      3,      5    ]  },  \"RetailersReceiptData\": {    \"ConsumerID\": \"d9e1c467-91c6-4afe-ae7c-86b0a0d0bfb3\",    \"RetailerID\": \"6da5da9f-b42d-4918-ad43-53b2203df54e\",    \"RetailerRulePoints\":     {      \"Enablexxx\": 1,      \"Enableyyy\": 1,      \"Enablezzz\": 1    }  }}";
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic obj  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        
        Console.WriteLine(obj.DigitalSignature);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ReceiptPublicKey);
    }
}
```

> MEYCIQDC0RutOfYEIR/3zkUlcIxxxxxx98Ayqq8AIhAP30+Bk8ueY1ABVYJlAQGlhAcWlAMHo3YAqhHIrUykUj
>
> RxxxxxIN7I3IhLjAqrUrx5vZofHYm4DF5srHB0Hzyuf25eW5UVCPOvbr8GvrzqZbq2ZdcQmAaoiyhaBcOdAsjcHYBcfV/tR5uHQRDLWIpNUTawcxB6tX6XGXvd0baPav4LfL2pfqegpx5BhfWdRGmvL6/Yc5bw29IWag/SmabTEZE/C4=

Comment: The OP seemed to be most interested in "RatingData". -- and the OP might not be aware that they can also get additional data from the JSON string like: `var ratingValue = obj.RatingData.RatingValue; Console.WriteLine(ratingValue);` and even extract the `Array` data: `var ratings = obj.RatingData.Rating;` then iterate through `foreach(var rating in ratings) { Console.WriteLine("rating: " + rating); }`

Comment: @Athanasios Kataras - your suggestion worked. Thanks